# Pregunta sobre la voz pasiva con "se"

Tags: se

Entiendo que en Español se puede decir, "La pintura fue creada por Picasso".

Pero, no sé si se puede decir lo mismo con la construcción pasiva con "se".

¿Es posible decir, "Se creó la pintura por Picasso"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. El uso del *se* pasivo impide la posibilidad de incluir un agente ajeno como en la voz pasiva ya que, por usar la construcción pasiva, existe un agente: solo es que coincide con el objeto directo/reflexivo que a la vez es también el sujeto.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: ¿Se puede decir, "A Picasso se le crearon las pinturas."?  @Diego

Comment: Se puede decir, si lo que intentas explicar es que alguien creó las pinturas para él (alguien mezcló los componentes que se necesitaban para crear las pinturas que Picasso necesitaba usar en sus lienzos: azul químico, rojo brillante, etc.) Las inflexiones de esa frase pueden merecer su propia pregunta en el foro. Por cierto, es Guifa quien ha respondido tu pregunta (kudos para él). Yo sólo he editado una letra que se le había escapado al teclear la respuesta.

Comment: @okarin Efectivamente como ha dicho Diego, la diferencia se puede ver en inglés. «A Picasso se le crearon las pinturas» quiere decir en inglés «the paintings were made *for* Picasso», aunque en este caso particular, la palabra *pintura* se entendería no como el cuadro sino las tintas/colores que ha usado